# Prevent `<a>` tags from redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I am trying to create a single-page application with a music player. That's why I want to prevent `<a>` tags from redirecting, which in turn causes the player to stop.
I tried several approaches such as:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
        event.preventDefault();
        navigate(event.target.href);
    }
});
```

or

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            navigate(event.target.href);
        });
    });
});
```

or

```html
<body onload="preventRedirect()">...</body>
```

```js
function preventRedirect(){
    const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener("click", event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            navigate(link.href);
        })
    })
}
```

Neither of these worked. The strange thing is, however, that if I execute the function or add the event listeners inside the console manually, everything finally works as expected.
I know that I should be using buttons, but that would break the aesthetics of my design.
I have tried setting the `href`s to "#" and using `onclick` to navigate, which works, but is tedious and I hope that my original idea will be able to work in the end.

Comment: `but that would break the aesthetics of my design` - that's what CSS was invented for :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I know. But I don't have time to replace all anchors with buttons and redo the CSS, too. That's one of my first projects and I'm trying new things. I'm a beginner, relax.

Comment: I am relaxed, I just mentioned it - anyway, your first code should work just fine

Comment: Of course, it does depend on the content of your `<a>` tags - which you didn't show

Comment: @JaromandaX The first (and now accepted) answer, which is like my first try, did work. I guess I did something wrong the first time. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have a SPAN inside the `<a>`? or some other element - that can effect the `event.target.tagName`

Comment: the other two methods should've worked too ... unless the `<a>` tags are added dynamically

Comment: Some of the `<a>` tags did have `<span>`s in them. And in this case the target was interpreted as the `<span>`, not the `a`, I guess. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to create a handler on the document level. It resembles your first code piece. Maybe the use of `navigate` (an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate)) is the culprit of that not working. It will throw an error, because you can't use it like that (it should be `[window].navigation.navigate(...)`, but using that it would follow the link).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest(`a`) /* && possible other conditions */) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`will not follow ${evt.target.href}`);
    evt.preventDefault();
    /* possibly more code */
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="https://www.google.com">(non clickable) link to Google</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.microsoft.com">(non clickable) link to Microsoft</a></p>
```

Comment: not so different to the first code the OP tried - which does exactly what OP wants - but does make sense depending on the content of the `<a>` tag :p

Comment: This worked. It resembles my first try. I guess I did something wrong the first time and that's why it didn't work until I tried again. Nevertheless, thank you very much. I wouldn't have tried this again without your answer. As you can see, I am a total noob in JS. Is there a simple explanation why this works and the other solutions didn't?

Comment: Hi @KotakaDanski, glad I could help., Edited my answer:  it may be the use of `navigate` in your function.

Comment: @KooiInc Yes, thankfully my IQ was sufficient for that, at least :-D

Comment: @KotakaDanski reading the later comments near your question, `evt.target.closest("a")` will circumvent the `spans` (or other html) not firing the click handler. Furthermore: it's not your IQ, it's just lack of experience probably. I have programmed js since 1996, but still there are plenty of moments that I'm flabbergasted by something not working the way I thougth it should have worked. Just persevere ;)

Comment: Thanks. I've had no formal education on JS in university and the little I've learned, I learned it by myself and just enough to push something acceptable for my needs (my experience is predominantly C++, Java, C#, HTML and CSS, almost no JS). Still, this is so obvious, I should have thought of it. Thank you so much again and have a great day!